# how can rotate shape in cst with code?

Tags: rotation

I wanna rotate shape's in cst with code , but Icant plz help me .
this is the help but I can do it :

Methods

```
Reset
```

> Resets all internal values to their defaults.

```
Name (name sObjectName)
```

> Defines the name of the object, the transformation should be applied to.

```
AddName (name sObjectName)
```

> Defines one more name of an additional object, in addition to the previously defined object. This is only used for transformations of solids with Origin set to CommonCenter, for TransformAlign and RotateAlign.

```
TranslateCurve / ScaleCurve / RotateCurve / MirrorCurve

TranslateWire / ScaleWire / RotateWire / MirrorWire

TranslateCoil / ScaleCoil / RotateCoil / MirrorCoil
```

> Translate / scale / rotate / mirror the selected object with all previously made settings.

```
Transform ( enum {"Shape","Port","Currentdistribution","Part"} what,  enum {"Translate", "Rotate", "Scale", "Mirror", "Matrix", "GlobalToLocal", "LocalToGlobal"} how )
```

> This execute a specified transform onto the given type of objects (named via Name and AddName). Note that not all transformations are applicable to all types of objects.

Comment: I mean , I wanna  write macro for rotate components

Comment: I found my answer , tnx